# MSSQL Date Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

i want to get sql date format as follow

[image: requre output]

this is i tried code

```
select case when
left(datepart(day,getdate()),1)=4 then concat(datepart(day,getdate()),'th',' of ',DATENAME(month,GETDATE()),' ',datepart(year,getdate()))
end
```

this is output from my query 4th of August 2020

Comment: try using this in your report design: = datepart("d",now())&"th of " & MonthName(month(now())) & " "  & datepart("YYYY",now())

Comment: 1th of June or 3th of August are valid with that.

Comment: @Ashan . . . Superscripts should be handled in the application layer.

Comment: In theory it is possible to write function that formats it, but there would be 4 case statements for day (case 1,21,31 - st, case 2,22 - nd, 3,23 - rd, else - th ) and ten concat string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @day int = datepart(day,getdate())

SELECT CONCAT(@day,
CASE WHEN @day=1 OR @day=21 OR @day=31 THEN 'st' 
 WHEN @day=2 OR @day=22 THEN 'nd' 
 WHEN @day=3 OR @day=23 THEN 'rd' ELSE 'th' END, ' of ',DATENAME(month,GETDATE()),' ',datepart(year,getdate()) )AS 'Date'
```

Would give you something like that.

Edit : if you make it as function, and pass it date as param you could use that pretty much anywhere. Will need to replace getdate() with parameter name then

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnc_GetDateString]
(
    @date DATETIME
)
RETURNS nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
 --DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2020-08-31'
  DECLARE @day int = datepart(day,@date)
  DECLARE @DateString nvarchar(100)
SET @DateString = CONCAT(@day,
CASE WHEN @day=1 OR @day=21 OR @day=31 THEN 'st' 
 WHEN @day=2 OR @day=22 THEN 'nd' 
 WHEN @day=3 OR @day=23 THEN 'rd' ELSE 'th' END, ' of ',DATENAME(month,@date),' ',datepart(year,@date) )

RETURN @DateString
END
```